# WPF - Is it possible to create this binding?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

Hi I would like create this binding. I have menu, something like this.

```
<Menu IsMainMenu="True" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
   <MenuItem Header="_MyMenu">
      <MenuItem Header="_Status">
         <MenuItem Name="Online" Header="Online" Click="StatusMenuItem_Click">
            <MenuItem.Icon>
               <Image Source="images\icons\menu\online.ico" Height="20"/>
            </MenuItem.Icon>
         </MenuItem>
      </MenuItem>
   </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

I would like create binding with menu item Name to string property of object, and as UpdateSourceTriger I would like have a event click on menu item.

Comment: Have you tried it and did it not work?

Comment: I doubt binding the Name would work as thats the objet's name, you can bind the header if you'd like to. also, bind the image's source.

Comment: But I need update property only when MENU ITEM IS CLICKED.

Comment: aaaaaaaahhhhhhh too many nested menus!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily solve this using a framework like Caliburn.Micro!

Answer (score 0):

What's the point in updating source? MenuItems do not provide any way to let user modify their Header. So even if you force Binding to update source your object will receive the same value it already contains. If you wish to notify the object that it's corresponding MenuItem was clicked you'd better use [Commands](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Silverlight-4-How-to-Command-Control.aspx) (the article describes Silverlight, but it's true for WPF too)